# How to open an access workbook and transfer a table into an excel worksheet using the VBA macro ran on Excel?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I had read that exporting an Excel worksheet from Access will use the `DoCmd` object and the `TransferSpreadsheet` method, however, I need a macro that will run from my Excel VBA script.

So the steps would be as following:

1. Run macro in Excel
2. Convert access table into an Excel worksheet
3. Excel VBA code runs a script on the newly converted worksheet.

Or if there was a way to

1. Run macro in Excel
2. Perform script on access table, the better.

Comment: It's currently unclear what you're asking. You can pretty much do anything in a single VBA macro, either from Excel or from Access.

Comment: Why don't you just import from Access into Excel: [Import Access Data](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/import-access-data.html) or [VBA Import from Access to Excel](http://www.onlinepclearning.com/import-from-access-to-excel/) there are even more tutorials out there in the www. So if you need a macro you will need to work through one of these tutorials and write one.

Comment: I know how to export an access table into an excel worksheet manually. However, what I really plan to achieve is run a macro that will compile several worksheets together in one click of an excel VBA code. Because our employees are working on several excel/access files and have the files saved on a cloud server. I wouldn't want to manually export each one by one but instead I plan to retrieve each file via the path of the file in the cloud

Comment: Then ask a question about that, and provide enough detail for me to be able to write an answer.

Comment: In you question you say you need to do it in Excel, now you say you want to do it on Access? What now? You need to be much more specific and ask a good question. Don't mix up import and export.

Comment: I will run the macro in excel VBA, but the excel macro will access the MS access objects and export the table. That's my goal. I don't plan to run 2 macros (one in excel and one in access). I was just wondering if I can access the Ms Access object similarly to that of excel (e.g. Workbooks("Test").Worksheets("Hello")) since they both use VBA

Comment: If you run code in VBA you want to IMPORT from Access to Excel. Please read the second link I gave in my first comment.

Comment: Thanks i'll read on it. Was just clarifying the question

Comment: Just to clarify: Import means your code runs in Excel and imports from Access. Export means your code runs in Access exports to Excel. So what you want to do is an import in Excel.

Comment: Yes that's what I plan to achieve was looking from the other perspective. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Pᴇʜ thanks this was 95% of the solution. 5% can easily be found by recording a macro and pressing the refresh button the vba code to refresh is there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your questions doesn't totally make sense, but I'm guessing that you want to import data from Access into Excel.  Is that right?

```
Import data from Access to Excel (DAO)

CopyFromRecordset is probably the easiest method of getting data from an Access table to an Excel worksheet.

Sub DAOCopyFromRecordSet(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: DAOCopyFromRecordSet "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", "FieldName", Range("C1")
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable) ' all records
    'Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
        " WHERE " & FieldName & _
        " = 'MyCriteria'", dbReadOnly) ' filter records
    ' write field names
    For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
    Next
    ' write recordset
    TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub

If you want more control with the data import, you can customize the macro below:

Sub DAOFromAccessToExcel(DBFullName As String, TableName As String, _
    FieldName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: DAOFromAccessToExcel "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", "FieldName", Range("B1")
Dim db As Database, rs As Recordset
Dim lngRowIndex As Long
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(TableName, dbOpenTable) ' all records
    'Set rs = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & _
        TableName & " WHERE " & FieldName & _
        " = 'MyCriteria'", dbReadOnly) ' filter records
    lngRowIndex = 0
    With rs
        If Not .BOF Then .MoveFirst
        While Not .EOF
            TargetRange.Offset(lngRowIndex, 0).Formula = .Fields(FieldName)
            .MoveNext
            lngRowIndex = lngRowIndex + 1
        Wend
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Or...

```
  Import data from Access to Excel (ADO)

With the procedure below you can import data from an Access table to a worksheet.

Sub ADOImportFromAccessTable(DBFullName As String, _
    TableName As String, TargetRange As Range)
' Example: ADOImportFromAccessTable "C:\FolderName\DataBaseName.mdb", _
    "TableName", Range("C1")
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, intColIndex As Integer
    Set TargetRange = TargetRange.Cells(1, 1)
    ' open the database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & _
        DBFullName & ";"
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        ' open the recordset
        .Open TableName, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable 
        ' all records
        '.Open "SELECT * FROM " & TableName & _
            " WHERE [FieldName] = 'MyCriteria'", cn, , , adCmdText 
        ' filter records

        RS2WS rs, TargetRange ' write data from the recordset to the worksheet

'        ' optional approach for Excel 2000 or later (RS2WS is not necessary)
'        For intColIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1 ' the field names
'            TargetRange.Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intColIndex).Name
'        Next
'        TargetRange.Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs ' the recordset data

    End With
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```